# How to test MongoDB aggregation performance?

Tags: mongodb, performance-testing

I have an aggregation operation in MongoDB, and want to test it's 1000 or more concurrent execution performance.

MongoDB have provided [benchRun](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/JavaScript-Performance-Testing-Harness), but no aggregation grammar found.
My code like below, the code doesn't matter:

```js
db.category.aggregate([ 
    {   $match: {city:'010'} }, 
    {
        $project: {
            "geometric_mean": { 
                $pow: [ $val, 2]
            }
        }
    },
    { $sort: {'geometric_mean': -1} }
],{ "allowDiskUse": true } );
```

How to use benchRun for aggregation, or is there any tool to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation is that you should not be testing the database directly, well-behaved [load test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) must mimic real System Under Test usage as close as possible so instead of hammering MongoDB with one query using 1000+ threads (which is not the best approach as well due to [results caching](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-handle-caching)) you should rather simulate 1000+ users using your application. I believe you will find way more things to worry about apart from the specific query performance.

---

If you're still looking for the way of load testing a MongoDB database using arbitrary code - you can check out [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it provides relatively easy ways of configuring a MongoDB connection and executing queries. Check out [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) article for comprehensive instructions if needed.